# Как стилизовать placeholder?

Tags: html, css

Хочу убрать рамку у плэйсхолдера и как-нибудь его украсить, но не могу понять как:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл лишь способ изменить цвет и расположение текста в нём:

```css
.trial__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 362px;
  width: 360px;
}

.trial__form ::placeholder {
  color: #b0b0b0;
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: -5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
}

.input__trial {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trial__form">
  <h2 class="trial__form_heading">Try Your <span class="form_span">FREE</span> Trial Today</h2>

  <input class="input__trial" type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <input class="input__trial" type="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input class="input__trial" type="password" placeholder="Password">

  <a href="" class="get__started">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну, рамки, вроде бы, можно убрать с помощью `border:none;`

Comment: Только сделайте это к псевдо-классу `:active` нужных `input`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рамка принадлежит не плейсхолдеру, а инпуту. Она появляется при фокусе на поле ввода. Ее можно убрать так:

```css
.input__trial:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло